# Разбитие двусвязного списка на основе массива на 2 части

Tags: c++, массивы, list

С трудом получилось допилить данный код, так как недавно начал изучать С++. 
Мне нужно разбить список, который задает пользователь на 2 части по значению элемента. Например, есть список "3 6 1 33 -4", пользователь выбирает единицу и получается 2 новых списка "3 6 1" и "33 -4", как-то так.
Идей никаких нет. Может кто-нибудь помочь с этим?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 50

int main(void)
{
    int list[MAX];
    int next[MAX];
    int prev[MAX];
    int end = 0;
    int begin = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        list[i] = next[i] = prev[i] = 0;
    }

    cout << "Input the number of elements: ";
    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    prev[0] = -1;
    cout << "Input elements of list: ";
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> list[i];
        next[i] = i + 1;
        prev[i] = i - 1;
        count++;
    }

    prev[0] = -1;
    next[count] = -1;
    begin = 0;
    end = count - 1;
    cout << "Elements of list: ";
    int temp = begin;

    do {
        printf("%d ", list[temp]);
        temp = next[temp];
    } while (next[temp] < n);

    cout << list[temp] << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Сделать 2 цикла. Первый копирует всё в первый список и проверяет на нужный элемент, если попался, то выходим, второй цикл копирует все оставшиеся элементы во второй список

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon в таком случае, проще сделать какой нибудь `bool` флаг, типа `bool valueFound = false`, а в теле цикла проверка на него, если `false` - копируем в первый список, если `true` - во второй. После чего Вы просто бежите по массиву копируя элементы в первый список. Как только найдете нужное число, скопируйте его в первый список и поставьте флаг в `true`

Comment: В результате у вас оба списка должны остаться в одном массиве или второй список должен размещаться с начала  другого массива? / Кстати, при вводе элементов надо бы проверять, что вы не выходите за размер массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int MAX = ?; // сами определите сколько
int list[MAX];     //  инициализируйте массив
int n;
cin >> n;
// сначала нужно определить размер этих списков
int *p = list;
while (*p++ != n);
const  int size1 = p - list,
        size2 = MAX - size1;
// а потом обьявить массив с такими размерами
int prev[size1],
        next[size2];
// дальше просто инициализация
for (int i = 0; i < size1; ++i) 
    prev[i] = list[i];   

for (int i = size1; i < MAX; ++i) 
    next[i - size1] = list[i];
```

P. S. Но причем тут двусвязный список _ я так и не понел...